# Deprecate required parameters after optional parameters in function/method

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have update PHPV 7 to PHP 8..1.2 Now whole my application lots of diffrent errors like this.
My main problem is how to solve this issue in the tcpdf library? i have updated the tcpf library the version is   "version": "6.3.2", please help me fint the solution.

"Deprecated: Optional parameter $isunicode declared before required parameter $currentfont is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\wamp64\www\prospecter\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_fonts.php on line 2024

Deprecated: Optional parameter $tidy_options declared before required parameter $tagvspaces is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\wamp64\www\prospecter\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php on line 1139

Deprecated: Optional parameter $prenom declared before required parameter $TheDate is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\wamp64\www\prospecter\class\Modules.php on line 929
Deprecated: number_format(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type float is deprecated

I works neraly 6 months in php so i need help to solve thease issuse in my app.

Comment: If you already got the newest(?) version of the library, and that is still not PHP 8 compatible, then it makes rather little sense to try and go fix these issues yourself. The TCPDF page has a note saying, _"A new version of this library is under development at https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf and as a consequence the old version will not receive any additional development or support."_ - so maybe you should try your luck with that version instead. That one appears to be compatible upwards to at least PHP 8.3.

Comment: The filenames in your error messages don't exist in the current version at that repo.

Comment: "lots of diffrent errors" - which error do you mean? You've shared deprecation notices, and they do (currently) not cause any harm to your application

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, these notices can't be fixed for the TCPDF library as that version isn't getting updated anymore.

The last 2 notices occur within your own code and can be fixed.

**First notice**

"Deprecated: Optional parameter $prenom declared before required parameter $TheDate is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\wamp64\www\prospecter\class\Modules.php on line 929"

Your code looks something like this:

```php
function foo($prenom = null, $TheDate) {
    // Your code
}
```

Because `$prenom` has a default value (making it optional) and `$TheDate` doesn't (making it required), you are receiving that notice telling you that the order of those parameters doesn't make sense as you can't give the second parameter without the first.

Change it to:

```php
function foo($prenom, $TheDate) {
    // Your code
}
// Alternatively, but you will have to change the order of passed variables in function calls
function foo($TheDate, $prenom = null) {
    // Your code
}
```

**Second**

"Deprecated: number_format(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type float is deprecated"

This happens because you're passing a variable that contains `null` instead of a float like `10.05` which is not going to be allowed anymore in the future.

If your code works fine regardless of this the easiest fix would be to cast the value to a float.

```php
$formatted = number_format((float)$number, 2);
```

Though the best fix would be to make sure `$number` can't be null.

**Other notices**

The other notices can be disabled by using the error_reporting() function, but I'd recommend to just disable error reporting for the production environment unless the notices themselves are causing issues in your application.

I hope this is clear enough and helps you out!

Comment: Thanks @K1ll3rM.your answer was helped me to solve Deprecated: number_format().., Deprecated: Optional parameter.., still i have tcpdf issue

Comment: @Je1111 Unless you fork the repository and fix them yourself I don't think they'll get fixed sadly, the notices shouldn't cause any issues right now but if it's possible you should switch to a different library

Comment: thanks Considering the potential issues with TCPDF notices, do you have any recommendations for alternative libraries that could be used as replacements? Your insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Je1111 PDF libraries are always a bitch to work with but I'd recommend having a look at [awesome-php](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#pdf) though [dompdf/dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) is probably the easiest to work with